# Cant install NodeMon (command not found: nodemon)

Tags: node.js, npm, zsh, nodemon, nvm

I'm trying to install NodeMon for my Node js project.
I have tried installing via npm.

> npm install nodemon

Provided following result

```
  npm WARN saveError ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/nodejs/package.json'
npm notice created a lockfile as package-lock.json. You should commit this file.
npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users//nodejs/package.json'
npm WARN nodejs No description
npm WARN nodejs No repository field.
npm WARN nodejs No README data
npm WARN nodejs No license field.
```

when i have tried running nodemon , It is throwing `command not found: nodemon)`
Let me know how i can fix this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed this by following below steps

**Step 1** npm initialisation in the same folder

```
npm init
```

> npm requests projectName , author , description , entry point

once provided , a package.json file will be added to your project folder.

**Step 2**

```
try npm install nodemon
```

It's Successful.

If still failing after following above steps , try with latest stable version of node and repeat the above process.

Comment: Means you haven't created the node project and was trying to install nodemon in it?

Comment: It worked after bumping my node version to latest LTS.

Answer (score 3):

I tried the following once i got into this issue and it did not work for me as well:

```
npm uninstall nodemon

sudo npm uninstall -g nodemon
```

then i tried this and it worked

```
sudo npm install -g --force nodemon
```